# Use Vowpal wabbit with probabilities as labels to predict probabilities

Tags: machine-learning, vowpalwabbit

I'm trying to use Vowpal Wabbit to predict probabilities given existing set of statistics. My txt file looks like that:

```
0.22 | Features1
0.28 | Features2
```

Now, given this example, I want to predict the label (probability) for Features3. I'm trying to use logistic regression:

```
vw -d ds.vw.txt -f model.p --loss_function=logistic --link=logistic -p probs.txt
```

But get the error :

```
You are using label 0.00110011 not -1 or 1 as loss function expects!
You are using label 0.00559702 not -1 or 1 as loss function expects!
```

etc..

How can I use these statistics as labels to predict probabilities?

Comment: Logistic regression implies binary-valued output. You sure you don't want linear regression?

Comment: @erip yes because the meaning of the output should be probabilities. All the output value should be between 0 and 1. Moreover, There are hundred of features and many can be missing for a specific row, therefore I suspect linear regression can be inaccurate

Answer (score 1):

To predict a continuous label you need to use one of the following loss functions:

```
--loss_function squared    # optimizes for min loss vs mean
--loss_function quantile   # optimizes for min loss vs median
```

`--loss_function squared` is the `vw` default, so you may leave it out.

Another trick you may use is to map your probability range into `[-1, 1]` by mapping the mid-point 0.5 to 0.0 using the function (2*probability - 1). You can then use `--loss_function logistic` which requires binary labels (`-1` and `1`), but follow the labels with `abs(probability)` as a floating point weight:

```
1 0.22 | features...
-1 0.28 | features...
```

This may or may not work better for your particular data (you'll have to hold-out some of your data and test your different models for accuracy.)

Background regarding binary outcomes: `vw` "starting point" (i.e null, or initial model) is 0.0 weights everywhere. This is why when you're doing a logistic regression, the `negative, positive` labels must be `-1, 1` (rather than `0, 1`) respectively.